# Overleaf project not compiling on local machine

Tags: pdftex, overleaf, miktex2.9

I have an overleaf project created using this [template](https://github.com/GarenSidonius/ASU-Dissertation-Template). The project works fine when compiled in draft (fast) mode but not in normal mode because I have tonnes of images in my project. In normal mode it just gives me a time-out error as show below.

[image]

So I downloaded the project on my local. I am using [texworks](https://www.tug.org/texworks/) GUI to compile it and convert to pdf. However, it gives me following error:

```
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibraryarrows.meta.c
ode.tex")
! Undefined control sequence.
l.487 \hook_gput_code:nnn
                          {begindocument} {chemformula}
```

I thought probably because `chemformula.sty` might be missing. but I went and checked I had that file present. I am using Miktex2.9. Entire output log is available [here](https://pastebin.com/pQ2C32L7). How do I make this work?

Comment: It looks like the error occurs already while loading the preamble. If so, then please post a minimal code which reproduces the issue.

Comment: Make sure to update all the packages (you have an older LaTeX).  In MiKTeX, LaTeX is in the `ltxbase` package (make sure to update in both user and admin mode)

Comment: i updated it, it did not work. i deleted it and installed again. it did not work either. if you just compile the template from github link it gives the following error: `! Argument of \extractpdftexversion has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.931     \extractpdftexversion\pdftexbanner\@nil}
                                                  
? `